# C#: What is the best collection class to store very similar string items for efficient serialization to a file

Tags: c#, serialization, collections

I would like to store a list of entityIDs of outlook emails to a file. The entityIDs are strings like:

"000000005F776F08B736B442BCF7B6A7060B509A64002000"
"000000005F776F08B736B442BCF7B6A7060B509A84002000"
"000000005F776F08B736B442BCF7B6A7060B509AA4002000"

as you can notice, the strings are very similar. I would like to save these strings in a collection class that would be stored as efficiently as possible when I serialize it to a file. Do you know of any collection class that could be used for this?

Thank you in advance for any information...
Gregor

Comment: It's a rather specialized requirement. I'd be surprised if there's something available out of the box.

Comment: Do you mean efficient in space or time?

Comment: @Martin: when you deal with IO operations these two usually go together.

Comment: What I mean is that they are very similar. It might be possible to create a custom object to spend some CPU time exploiting this to reduce the size of the data serialized. Perhaps in a similar manner to zip. I guess that would likely speed up the I/O as well though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [Radix Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) data-structure, as this would be able to efficiently store your keys.

As far as serialising to a file, you could, perhaps, walk the trie and write down each node.  (In the following example I have used indentation to signify the level in the tree, but you could come up with something a bit more efficient, such as using control characters to signify a descent or ascent.)

```
00000000
  5F776F08B736B442BCF7B6A7060B509A
    64002000
    84002000
    A4002000
  6F776F08B736B442BCF7B6A7060B509A
    32100000
```

The example above is the set of:

```
000000005F776F08B736B442BCF7B6A7060B509A64002000
000000005F776F08B736B442BCF7B6A7060B509A84002000
000000005F776F08B736B442BCF7B6A7060B509AA4002000
000000006F776F08B736B442BCF7B6A7060B509A32100000
```

Answer (score 8):

No pre-existing collection class from the framework will suit your needs, because these are generic: by definition, they know nothing of the type they are storing (e.g. `string`) so they cannot do anything with it.

If efficient serialization is your only concern, I suggest that you simply compress the serialized file. Data like this are a feast for compression algorithms. .NET offers gzip and deflate algorithms in [`System.IO.Compression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx); better algorithms (if you need them) can easily be found through Google.

If in-memory efficiency is also an issue, you could store your strings in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Dictionary_representation) or a [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree).

Answer (score -3):

Why is efficient an issue? Do you want to use as less HD space as possible (HD space is cheap).
In C# there 2 most used serializers:
[Binary](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file)
or [XML](http://devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=236)

If you want the user to let the file be adjustable with notepad for example --> use xml. If not use binary

Comment: "Don't think, ram is cheap" - this is how crap software is built.